# node_modules not resolved, local absolute modules work fine

Tags: typescript, webpack

So this has been agonizing, but my baseUrl is working, and my files load correctly, however, for example trying to `import Chalk from 'chalk` I get this error.

```sh
i ｢atl｣: Using typescript@3.6.3 from typescript
i ｢atl｣: Using tsconfig.json from C:/Users/adria/Desktop/backup/Business/repositories/xTouch/tsconfig.json
i ｢atl｣: Checking started in a separate process...
i ｢atl｣: Time: 719ms
Hash: 13062a08d1faecf0a32b
Version: webpack 4.40.2
Time: 2119ms
Built at: 09/19/2019 12:50:05 AM
 1 asset
Entrypoint main = xtouch.js
[0] ./src/CommandBase.ts 195 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/xtouch.ts 670 bytes {0} [built]
[2] ./src/XTouchCommandManager.ts 648 bytes {0} [built]
[3] ./src/CommandHandler.ts 1.67 KiB {0} [built]
[4] ./src/CommandEcho.ts 512 bytes {0} [built]
[5] ./src/CommandHelp.ts 552 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./src/xtouch.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chalk' in 'C:\Users\adria\Desktop\backup\Business\repositories\xTouch\src'
 @ ./src/xtouch.ts 4:16-32
error Command failed with exit code 2.
```

I've tried various things and it just isn't working.

```js
// config/webpack.config.ts
const config: Configuration = {
  entry: path.resolve(appSrc, 'xtouch.ts'),
  mode: 'production',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: outDir,
    filename: 'xtouch.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.ts', '.json'],
    modules: ['node_modules', appNodeModules].concat(appSrc || []),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.ts/,
        loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default config;
```

#### File Structure (for context)

- config/

  - paths.ts
  - webpack.config.ts
- node_modules/
- src/

  - xtouch.ts
  - XTouchCommandManager.ts
  - etc.
- tsconfig.json
- package.json

You can even find the public repository [here](https://github.com/XplorationByAdrian/xTouch). This is really stressing me out.

Comment: I was wondering if the module "chalk“ is installed...

Comment: It is, I finally found the error

Comment: @TheGrimSilence Can you answer your question in case you found the solution. It may be helpful to those who face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, I had `[ '.ts', '.ts' ]` instead of `[ '.js','.ts']` and that locked out all node modules